# Using void object as a generic object type in C++

Tags: c++

I have a dll that honours an interface I was given.  In this there are a number of methods that rely on an object type defined in a header I do not have.  For example

```
STDMETHOD(OnPrepareNextScan)(BOOL* isSurvey, long curExp, ExtractMethod* pEM,
            unsigned long scanTime, double* selectedMass, double* selectedIntensity) = 0;
```

The header defines the ExtrctMethod type  However, I dot care about this object, I am not going to use it, so I as wondering if I could use a void pointer instead.

Comment: How do you compile this if ExtractMethod isn't present in any headers?

Answer (score 4):

Just use a forward declaration to enable the undefined type, and pass a NULL to the function.

```
class ExtractMethod;

OnPrepareNextScan(isSurvey, curExp, NULL, scanTime, selectedMass, selectedIntensity);
```